# Regex not ending with, without lookahead or lookbehind

Tags: regex

It's sad but my regex library does not support lookahead and lookbehind assertions.

Is it possible to create a regex which match strings not ending with my pattern, `foobar\d\d` for example?

Comment: Does the solution have to be purely in a single regex, or can you do something like `pattern1.matches(string) and not pattern2.matches(string)`?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, it's a complicated structure without direct access to strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, although a bit verbose. Say you want your string not to end with `abc`, here's a regex for it:

```
([^c]|[^b]c|[^a]bc)$
```

Note that this won't match strings like `c` or `bc`. To match those, the regex becomes more complicated:

```
([^c]|[^b]c|[^a]bc|^|^c|^bc)$
```